# ReactiveSearch, DataSearch and indexing user query

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, indexing, reactivesearch

I'm using the DataSearch from Reactivesearch for an autocomplete feature and I'm trying to figure out how I can take the user's selected query and add that to my autocomplete index hosted at Appbaseio?

When I say user's selected query, I mean a query either typed in OR selected from DataSearch component dropdown list.

Here is what I've come up with so far

```
<DataSearch
   componentId="SearchSensor"
   dataField={["original_title"]}
   className="search-bar"
   onValueSelected={
     function(value, cause, source) {
       console.log("current value: ", value)
     }
   }
   iconPosition="right"
   innerclassName={{
     list: "text-item"
   }}
   />
```

The onValueSelected above is taken straight from the [docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html#extending). It seems that is the property that I need to work with in order to do this. I'm just not sure how to connect it to my Appbaseio ES index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onValueSelected` is the correct approach to get the selected value here. (You can also get the full query with `onQueryChange` if needed). After getting this selected value in `onValueSelected` you can index this using a simple `fetch` request to your elasticsearch index or send it to a backend. There's also a [helper library](https://github.com/appbaseio/appbase-js) and the [docs](https://docs.appbase.io/rest-quickstart.html) for rest you can try.

Also I would recommend pulling the indexing logic to a server instead of exposing it on client side since you would need the write credentials in order to perform a write. This would keep your write credentials safer.

For example:

```
<DataSearch
  ...
  onValueSelected={(value) => {
    fetch('YOUR_SERVER_URL' or 'Elasticsearch URL', { method: 'POST', body: {...} })
  }
/>
```

Comment: if I use appbase-js to interact with my Appbaseio ES, how would I call the indexing logic on the Node app with onValueSelected?

Comment: You would have to create a route on your server which receives the selected value and then use the `index` method from appbase-js [docs](https://docs.appbase.io/javascript/quickstart.html#storing-data)

Comment: as I've done more testing, now I realize what you mean by using onQueryChange to get the WHOLE query - thanks for the heads up! Still learning but getting better with ReactiveSearch!

Comment: follow up to this. If I'm going to use a paid plan from Appbase - I don't have to worry about indexing user queries - it seems I can get the same query data from Appbase - is that right?

Comment: Not really sure about this. Would be best to consult with support imo